# A 3-valued mathematical logic?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, soft-question, puzzle

Classical propositional logic is consistent and in conformity with human language. A formal statement is true or not true and it is possible to develope rules with which it is possible decide which statements are true or not. It is a consistent system for classifying formal statements.

Mathematical statements could be unconditionally true $(x\notin\emptyset)$ named 1, conditionally true $(x\in S)$ named 2 or unconditionally false $(x\in\emptyset)$ named 0. I'm interested to find out if there are consistent and useful systems for classifying mathematical statements with these three values with likewise good conformity with human language.

I thought there where no problems with $\wedge$, $\vee$ or $\iff$:

```
or  0 1 2  
  0 0 1 2 
  1 1 1 1  
  2 2 1 2

and 0 1 2
  0 0 0 0
  1 0 1 2
  2 0 2 2

iff 0 1 2
  0 1 0 2
  1 0 1 2
  2 2 2 2
```

But as skyking commented the combination (2,2) might result in 0,1 or 2 depending on the statements. However the result of (2,2) could maybe be $0+1+2$ ($+$ is exclusive or)?

Is it possible to define $\neg$, $\implies$ and $+$ in a consistent way using corresponding words in human language as boundary conditions? That is, so that the connectives are consistent but not contra intuitive?

Comment: I don't think that description of the truth is consistent with the truth tables. Two conditionally true statements can be (unconditionally) equivalent (or unconditionally non-equivalent), their disjunction may be unconditionally true and their conjunction may be unconditionally false.

Comment: Google 3 valued logic - theres heaps of them, for precisely the reason that the connectives you havent defined a hard to define such that they have nice properties

Comment: The way you are distinguishing between true in all situations and true in some situations makes me think that you are looking for modal logic.

Comment: @skyking, you are right. The compositions aren't closed. I'll see if I can find out a solution.

Comment: See [Kleene's Three-valued logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/#ThrValSys) and [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: The SEP article is woefully incomplete on Kleene's 3-valued logic. Quite unfortunate.

Comment: @user21820 - for more, see: Merrie Bergmann, [An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=zEwNfoAZEGoC&pg=PA71) (2008), **Ch.5 Three-Valued Propositional Logics**, page 71-on, as well as: Melvin Fitting, [Kleene's Three Valued Logics and Their Children](http://philpapers.org/rec/FITKTV).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Ah I found the latter but not the former. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by *skyking*, your definition does not work. Take any statement $P$ that is not provable (Your example of "$x \in S$" is one if you allow non-sentences). Then $( P \lor \neg P )$ is unconditionally true, but you would have assigned it the 'truth-value' $2$. So your definition is self contradictory.

However, what you seem to want is Kleene's 3-valued logic, where the third truth value is intended to represent "unknown". Then your truth tables match. But this is still not about conditional truth. (You cannot allow non-sentences to be statements, otherwise you will have inconsistency.)